# Which shortcuts create for deployment of the non-metro applications on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, shortcut

If you make deployment of your non-metro (old style) application you have basically two options:

- put the shortcut to the main executable file in the start menu
  (default and recommended by the guidelines for the Windows Logo)
- put the shortcut to the main executable file on the desktop (optional).

There is no start menu in the Windows 8 RTM. How do I create a program's shortcut for the non-metro applications in the Windows 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non-Store apps, if you specify the Start menu for an icon, it is added to the new Windows 8 Start Page.  If you specify an app for the desktop, it will be added to the desktop.

Comment: I've found that desktop shortcuts for non-Metro apps in the Windows 8 cannot be removed from the old-style desktop. In this case Windows Shows a confirm Dialog that the exe file will be deleted. Is it a new feature? How to delete the shortcut only?